# Como desmarcar uma CheckBox ao marcar outra?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Gostaria que isso não pudesse acontecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário ao clicar na outra `CheckBox`, desativasse a que fora marcada anteriormente.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package genesysgeneration.umouoto;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CheckBox cb01, cb02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cb01=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb01);
        cb02=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb02);

        addCheckBoxChecked();

    }

    public void addCheckBoxChecked(){

        cb01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){



                }

            }
        });

        cb02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Não é mais facil usar radiobutton nao?

Comment: pensei nisso e iria colocar em uma observação na pergunta. Não, ele não me serve.

Comment: Porque o radiobutton não serve?

Comment: Creio que o radiobutton pode trabalhar com agrupamentos (duplas, trios), porém pretendo criar activitys em que as condições não sejam tão simples assim, coisas que não são necessariamente contrárias, opostas, excludentes. Terá casos em que o usuário tenha de selecionar por exemplo 6 de 8 itens.

Comment: Mas nada impede para este caso em especifico implementar radiobutton. E pelo que estou vendo, você terá que trabalhar com listeners cruzados entre os dois checkboxes para tratar isso, veja esta resposta no SOEn:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13133373/5524514

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O ideal é usar [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) e [`RadioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton), no entanto respondendo sua pergunta, usando `CheckBox`, uma das formas é fazer deste jeito:

```
cb01.setChecked(true);
cb01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (cb01.isChecked())
            cb02.setChecked(false);
        else cb02.setChecked(true);
    }
});

cb02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (cb02.isChecked())
            cb01.setChecked(false);
        else cb01.setChecked(true);
    }
});
```

Lembrando que pode ser escrito em outras lógicas de programação além desta.

Como você não especificou muito bem o mótivo de ser `CheckBox`, se caso for uma questão de *layout*, você pode usar o `RadioButton` e definir o como estilo do `CheckBox`. Desta forma, bastaria acrescentar o estilo customizado o do botão em seu `style.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"> 
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>
</style>
```

Leia mais na documentação:

- [CheckBoxes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html)
- [RadioButton and RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO CARA!!!

Irei dar uma olhada nessa parada do RadioButton, porém creio que ele realmente não me serve.